# Evaluate: $\lim_{x\to5}\left(\dfrac{\log{(x+5)}-\log{(5-x)}}{x-5}\right)$

Tags: limits, logarithms

> Evaluate: $\lim_{x\to5}\left(\dfrac{\log{(x+5)}-\log{(5-x)}}{x-5}\right)$

If we put $x=5$, we get $\dfrac{\infty}{0}$ form, which is not an indeterminate form, right?

So, I was tempted to write 'not defined' as answer. Yet I half-heartedly applied L'Hospital but didn't get any answer. I expanded $\log$ series. Still no answer.

Even after looking at the following solution, I am not able to understand it.

$$\lim_{x\to5}\left(\frac{\log(x+5)-\log(5-x)}{x-5}\right)\\=\lim_{x\to5}\left(\frac{(\log(x+5)-\log5)-(\log(5-x)-\log5)}{x-5}\right)\\=\lim_{x\to5}\left(\left(\frac{\log(x+5)-\log5}{x-5}\right)-\left(\frac{\log(5-x)-\log5}{x-5}\right)\right)\\=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\left(\frac{\log(x+5)-\log5}{x-5}\right)+\left(\frac{\log(5-x)-\log5}{5-x}\right)\right)\\=\frac15+\frac15=\frac25$$

I don't understand why and how the limit changed to $x\to0$.

Comment: I think $\frac{\infty}{0}$ is an indeterminate form

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is designed for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}.$  Noting that $k = \log(10)$ is a **fixed finite** term, at $x = 5$, your expression evaluates to $\frac{k - (-\infty)}{0}$ which clearly represents **positive** unbounded growth.  So, as $x \to 5$, the expression goes to $+\infty.$

Comment: @user2661923 I thought the same, but the answer is different.

Comment: Minor quibble: actually, the above comment applies as $x$ approaches $5$, from below (i.e. where $x$ is slightly smaller than $5$).  For $x > 5$, the expression is actually undefined, because you can't take the logarithm of a negative number.

Comment: Is the answer different from my last comment?

Comment: @user2661923 To be honest, I thought the same, once again.

Comment: Then, what is the answer that is supposed to be correct?

Comment: @user2661923 The answer is $\dfrac25$. I have posted the solution too.

Comment: @user2661923 Doesn't the expression tend to $-\infty$

Comment: @Asher2211 Yes, as $x$ approaches $5$ from below, the expression does tend to $-\infty$.  However, I realized that too late, and I couldn't edit my original comment, since more than 5 minutes had elapsed.

Comment: The correct answer is not $2/5$. You are right that you don't get an indeterminate form when substituting $5$ in the expression, but you must take care because the limit only makes sense for $x\to 5^-$, so you get $\infty/0^-$ which is $-\infty$.

Comment: @StefanOctavian Thanks.

Comment: The analysis in your answer is wrong.  Namely, $$\lim_{x \to 5^{-}} \left[\log(5 + x) - \log(5-x)\right]$$ does not exist.  Therefore, any algebraic manipulation (e.g. involving changing the limit to $x \to 0^{-}$) is invalid.  Did this analysis come from a book or a teacher?

Comment: @user2661923 it's from a website. [Here](https://www.sarthaks.com/528826/evaluate-lim-x5-log-x-5-log-5-x-x-5) is the link. Generally, it's quite a reliable website. Also, I have seen the exact solution on another website as well.

Comment: Bizarrely Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x:=5-\mathrm e^{-t}\;\,(t>0)$. Then
$$\lim_{x\to5}\frac{\log(x+5)-\log(5-x)}{x-5}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\log(10-\mathrm e^{-t})+t}{\mathrm e^{-t}}=\infty.$$
So there is no limit. The change of the $x$ limit to $x\to0$ in the solution you cite is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever indeterminate form is $\frac{\infty}{0}$ the limit is $\infty$ (largest number divided by the smallest number is the largest). No method is required to find limit. Similarly the form $\frac{0}{\infty}$ means the limit is 0.

So the answer of your limit is $\infty$, you may also say limit does not exist.
You may apply L'Hôpital to appreciate this again.
$$L=\lim_{x\to5^+}\left(\dfrac{\log{(x+5)}-\log{(5-x)}}{5-x}\right)$$
Differentiating up and down separately. we get
$$\lim_{x \to 5^{+}}\left(\frac{1}{x+5}+\frac{1}{5-x}\right)=-\infty$$

Comment: Please see my correction.

Comment: No it is correct as the derivative of $5-x$ is -1.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<x<5;$

Rewrite:

$-\left(\dfrac{1}{5+x}\right) \dfrac{\log(\dfrac{5-x}{5+x})}{\dfrac{5-x}{5+x}};$

The first factor $\rightarrow 1/(10).$

Second factor:

Set $t:=\dfrac{5-x}{5+x}$ and consider the limit

$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+ }\dfrac{\log t}{t}.$